# Echad Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yaakov was 121 years old when the events of "miketz shnasayim yamim" happened (130 when he arrived minus 2 years of famine and 7 years of sava)

Answer (score 4):

121 are the *dapim* in *Y'vamos*. 121 is also the number of the last *daf* in *P'sachim*.

Answer (score 1):

Parshas Veira has 121 Pesukim